# Measuring elm performance

Tags: performance, elm

I'm developing an application using elm-ui library. It's really great but once in a while I experience small delays. I tried to profile my app using chrome but there is nothing more than FPS drop that I can read from it.

How do you measure and find root cause of performance problems in elm?

Comment: Elm is transpiled to JavaScript code, so you would need to profile the generated JS. I assume that's what you have done already with browser dev tools. AFAIK, it is not possible to profile Elm code directly. You mention a FPS drop, that sounds like clue and should be investigated more. Unfortunately deciphering JS generated from Elm is not trivial.

Comment: @kaskelotti Do you know any tips about what and where in JS I should look?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have only briefly looked at the generated JS and noticed it being non-trivial. In general, performance issues tend to be localized. What I mean is that usually there's a small piece of code that causes these issues. With profiler you might be able to find the function that is causing issued. I briefly looked at the transpiled JS code on one of projects and the type names for example seemed to remain, at least partly, with prefixes such as `$author$project`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [elm-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-monitor) to see if the FPS drop is consistent with a certain pattern of actions / state transitions.